Jetty server 11.0.20: Failed startup of context
WARNING: Failed startup of context
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@a38c7fe Jun 13, 2024 5:43:03 PM
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@e19bb76{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Jun 13, 2024 5:43:03 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart 
INFO: Started Server@568ff82{STARTING}[11.0.20,sto=5000] @740ms

When i access localhost:8080 , i am getting http status code of 503.
Any help would be highly appreciated , Thanks in advance.
I have tried clean and rebuild the application, no luck.

Your question lacks details on what steps you did to reach this point.  Please edit your question and provide more details.
